# "error: wrong helper.h inclusion" compilation error in Kernel module build

Tags: c, linux, gcc, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I am trying to add new C file **newfile_test.c** in a kernel module. The C file has a `#include <linux/types.h>` and no other include files present. Existing kernel module source code already has a header **"helper.h"** which includes the same `<linux/types.h>` file.

Whenever I compile, I get below error for my newly added C file.

***newfile_test.c(1) : error: wrong helper.h inclusion***

**Note**: Line no.1 of the newfile_test.c is nothing but `#include <linux/types.h>` line.

If I remove `<linux/types.h>` include from the C file and add "helper.h" there, the compilation gets success. But I don't want to use helper.h in the file.

I don't know why the includes in my new C file are compared against some unrelated header file in the source code and being complained as compilation error in the C file.

Can anyone please help me understand the issue better?

TIA!

The compile error log looks like(changed the filename and paths per my need):

`CC [M]  /home/ramesh/ko/newfile_test.o
MF      /home/ramesh/ko/newfile_test.c
/home/ramesh/ko/newfile_test.c(1) : error: wrong helper.h inclusion
make[1]: *** [/home/ramesh/ko/newfile_test.o] Error 1`

Comment: The message `error: wrong helper.h inclusion` doesn't look like emitted by the `gcc` compiler. How emits this message? (That is, after what action you observe this message and where?)

Comment: @Tsyvarev I have added the snipped compile log for you

Comment: Until you post an [MCVE] that would let others replicate the behavior, I think there is really not that much others can do. What is your makefile? Can you run ex. `make --debug=j` or something like that to track what command outputs the "wrong inclusion" message?

Comment: First time see the step `MF` in the build log. Please, show your `Makefile`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev you are right. Looks like it wasn't from gcc. In my build system, the CC macro is modified in the makefile, which has a script throwing this error. Thanks for your help. Without your hint, I would have stuck at that point thinking it is a gcc problem.